# How to exclude files from a created, but not completed pull request?

Tags: git, azure-devops

Good afternoon!
A person created a pull request, but before creating it, he merged a branch from another, and changes of other files got into the branch, from where the pull request was created. How to remove these files from the created pull request so that after its execution the changes to them will not be applied?

Comment: It would be simpler to withdraw the pull request, undo the merge, and start over and create the pull request correctly this time.

Comment: Conceptually, forget about the pull request for a moment. Clean up the local branch the way you want it, and then (force) push it out to the remote. From there either the PR will be updated automatically, or as matt said you can abandon the PR and create a new one with the corrected branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can revert the changes that A person merged from another branch.

Let's say you created a PR from **A branch** to **B branch** , But A person merged some unwanted changes to **A** from **C branch**. Now you donot want the changes from C branch be merged to B branch. You can run the `git revert` command to revert A branch to the state before merged C branch. See below example git commands:

```
git checkout A

#git log --oneline #find the commit hash of the merge with git log
#git revert -m 1 [commit-hash] 

git revert -m 1 HEAD   #revert A branch to the before-merge state
git push #push A back to remote server
```

Then the A branch of the PR will updated and the unwanted changes for C branch will be removed. See [Undoing Merges](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#_undoing_merges) for more information.

`Git revert` command will keep the merge history, which will cause the changes in C branch not being able to merge back to A branch again. You can also check out [this blog](https://www.datree.io/resources/git-undo-merge). If you want A branch go back to original state before merged C branch(remove the merge history), You can use the `git reset` and `git push --force` commands. See below example:

```
git checkout A
git reset --hard HEAD~
git push --force
```